# Pandas plot three dataframes on the same figure

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, merge, bar-chart

I have tried many different solutions, but it seems I can't make it work.
I have nine dataframes (each 3 describe a system):

```
df = pd.read_csv('purged_0.csv', sep=',', header=6, usecols=['Location', 'TOTAL', 'Unnamed: 19'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('purged_1.csv', sep=',', header=6, usecols=['Location', 'TOTAL', 'Unnamed: 19'])
df3 = pd.read_csv('purged_2.csv', sep=',', header=6, usecols=['Location', 'TOTAL', 'Unnamed: 19'])
...
df9 = pd.read_csv('purged_8.csv', sep=',', header=6, usecols=['Location', 'TOTAL', 'Unnamed: 19'])
```

which look like this:

```
               TOTAL_x  Unnamed: 19_x   TOTAL_y  Unnamed: 19_y     TOTAL  Unnamed: 19  total_mean  error_mean
Location                                                                                                 
LEU 455  -2.000507       0.043331 -1.822317       0.037883 -1.818721     0.030111   -1.880515    0.037108
PHE 456  -1.956130       0.041076 -2.305222       0.033210 -2.281509     0.042238   -2.180954    0.038842
ALA 475  -1.493856       0.085664 -2.950011       0.053675 -1.387676     0.068704   -1.943848    0.069348
GLY 476  -0.941795       0.079101 -2.383338       0.056897 -0.871813     0.062222   -1.398982    0.066073
PHE 486  -2.999369       0.081517 -3.688329       0.074005 -2.439233     0.093345   -3.042310    0.082956
ASN 487  -0.828214       0.080111  0.497831       0.029272 -0.969843     0.130934   -0.433409    0.080106
GLN 493  -1.323107       0.152173 -1.902454       0.121394 -2.320519     0.131299   -1.848694    0.134955
GLY 496  -0.603422       0.094210  0.069107       0.009226  0.120265     0.015929   -0.138017    0.039788
GLN 498  -2.692248       0.163207 -0.345707       0.051059 -1.610146     0.135108   -1.549367    0.116458
PRO 499  -0.256722       0.016657  0.042420       0.020137 -0.198196     0.011229   -0.137499    0.016008
THR 500  -0.650186       0.099639 -0.862829       0.113726 -0.996115     0.093840   -0.836377    0.102402
ASN 501  -3.513380       0.093578 -3.364489       0.090704 -4.055331     0.081724   -3.644400    0.088669
GLY 502  -1.011485       0.042847 -0.848697       0.054364 -0.712001     0.046970   -0.857395    0.048060
VAL 503  -0.680188       0.046426 -0.825084       0.082318 -0.635653     0.034014   -0.713642    0.054252
TYR 505  -1.868647       0.089418 -2.091676       0.084795 -1.777963     0.089681   -1.912762    0.087965
```

I have then merged them 3 by 3 (the argv is just a number I put to correct the labels,nothing big):

```
merge1 = pd.merge(df, df2, how='inner', on='Location')
merge2 = pd.merge(merge1, df3, how='inner', on='Location')
merge2 = merge2.loc[(df['TOTAL'] <= -0.25) & df['Location'].str.startswith("L")]
merge2.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
merge2.set_index('Location', inplace=True)
merge2.index = merge2.index.str.split()
merge2.index = merge2.index.str[1] + ' ' + ((merge2.index.str[2].astype(int)) + int(sys.argv[10]) - 1).astype(str)
merge2['total_mean'] = merge2[['TOTAL_x', 'TOTAL_y', 'TOTAL']].mean(axis=1)
merge2['error_mean'] = merge2[['Unnamed: 19_x', 'Unnamed: 19_y', 'Unnamed: 19']].mean(axis=1)
```

I can correctly plot them one by one with:

```
concat = pd.concat([merge2,merge4,merge6])
pd.DataFrame.plot(concat)
plt.show()
```

But since it's a comparison, I would like to plot everything on the same figure(something like this):
[image]

So far I have tried to concatenate the different dataframes,and tried pyplot as well, and experimented with pandas.DataFrame.plot:

```
plt.bar(merge2.index, merge2['total_mean'])
plt.bar(merge4.index, merge4['total_mean'])
plt.bar(merge6.index, merge4['total_mean'])

test = pd.merge(merge2, merge4, how='inner', on='Location')
test.plot(y='total_mean', kind='bar', yerr='error_mean', legend=False)
```

But to no avail.

I would like to plot the three independent merged dataframes (merged2(which is (df+df2)+df3, merged4 (df4+df5)+df6, merged6 (df7+df8)+df9) showing only the 'total_mean' colum and using the 'error_mean' as error bar.

I can make it work with one, and independently I can plot them, but it's a total disaster if I try to put them all sharing the y axis.

Thank you for your help!

Ludovico

Comment: What is the data structure of merge2 (or 4 or 6, which should be comparable as I understand your question)? I assume the index is `Location` and goes on the x-axis, two columns 'total_mean' and 'error_mean' provide the bar information, and 2/4/6 are the three groups in your final graph. Any irregularities we should know about these dataframes?

Comment: No they are all similar. In addition I .dropna so the shape should be regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved simply by putting an array of colors... it's not specified anywhere but when you concatenate you can keep the original colors by adding an array like color=['r', 'g', 'b']).
Here is the modification I used, in case anyone would know:

```
    concat = pd.concat(merged_data_frames, axis=0, sort=True)
    concat = concat.sort_index(key=lambda x: x.str.split().str[1].str.zfill(5))
    concat.plot(kind='bar', y='total_mean', use_index=True, yerr='error_mean', edgecolor='black', color=['r', 'g', 'b'])
```